# Unexpected Token Error: Yarn Local Package Dependency

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I'm currently working with this module called react-vertical-tree. I was hoping to edit some of the code that's on the Github repository and test it with my project. I used yarn-link to try to link the local files with my project and I'm getting an error:

"Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:8) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.12",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-vertical-tree": "../react-vertical-tree",
    "serve": "^11.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "ts-essentials": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "eslint-check": "eslint --print-config ./src/App.tsx | eslint-config-prettier-check"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

I haven't made any edits to the react-vertical-tree files so I'm not sure what's wrong.

I've tried fixing my configurations on package.json but nothing has really helped.

Comment: It seems like it's a webpack issue. Can you share your `webpack.config` file

Comment: https://github.com/seviltagiyeva/react-vertical-tree/blob/master/webpack.config.js is the link for the webpack.config of react-vertical-tree!